# Proper term for knowing four or more languages?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, vocabulary, prefixes

If *bilingual* means you know two languages, and *trilingual* means you know three, what would be the proper term for knowing four, five or even six languages?

Comment: Now, for the term in the opposite direction, that's a classical joke: What do you call someone who speaks three languages? Trilingual. What do you call someone who speaks two languages? Bilingual. What do you call someone who speaks one language? American.

Comment: I would answer "polylingual" or "polyglot" or something else along those lines; but technically, the prefix "poly" tends to start at three, and not at four.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[Polyglot](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Polyglot):

> - person having a speaking, reading, or writing knowledge of several languages.

(AHD)

Comment: Once, twice, thrice, many. That's all we use in English. And _trilingual_ isn't used often.

Comment: @JohnLawler We do use quad in some cases in English... quart, quarter, quaternary, quadrilateral, etc.

Comment: And we use quintessence, sextuplets, and Septuagint as well. But they're fossils of the Latin embedded in English words. They're not productive.

Comment: @JohnLawler And octopuses! Don't forget the octopuses! (Yeah, all right, so it's Greek—the number bit is still the same.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Isn't that octopi?

Comment: @Angew Definitely not, no. _Octopi_ is by far my least favourite plural of that word. Personally, I quite like _octopodes_ and usually use that, but I’m slowly moving toward _octopuses_.

Comment: Also, "hyperpolyglot" is coined for a person who can speak six or more languages fluently.

Comment: As there's been a recent surge of suggested edits, the one approved for your post is technically superfluous because now your post has two identical links. To "comply" with the "rules"  the initials: **TFD** or *The Free dictionary* without the url address is suffice.

Comment: For most people, three would already be "several". For some, being polyglot starts with 5 or 6. Nevertheless, it's probably the best match the OP can get.

Answer (score 30):

**[Multilingual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilingualism#Multilingual_individuals)**:

> A multilingual person, in a broad definition, is one who can communicate in more than one language, be it actively (through speaking, writing, or signing) or passively (through listening, reading, or perceiving). More specifically, the terms bilingual and trilingual are used to describe comparable situations in which two or three languages are involved. *A multilingual person is generally referred to as a polyglot*. Poly (Greek: πολύς) means "many", glot (Greek: γλώσσα) means "language".

From Wikipedia, the online encyclopedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilingualism#Multilingual_individuals

Comment: Multilingualism focuses on communication rather than mastering the language with its all aspects. Though, multilingual is used as a synonym of polyglot also.

Comment: @ermanen the OP asked about knowing several languages, not mastering them :)

Comment: @Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt: I know. I'm giving extra information and mentioning the differences.

Answer (score 6):

[quadrilingual](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quadrilingual):

> Able to speak four languages.

Comment: Unfortunately, this limits the meaning to *only* 4 languages.

Comment: The question makes it sound like he needs the equivalent of "trilingual" for 4, 5 and 6.

Comment: @PierreArlaud that's exactly right, but polyglot also works.

Comment: quintilingual and sextlingual?

Comment: Reference, please.

Answer (score 6):

If you know ***more than 3*** languages, you are ***supertrilingual***.

(Which, of course, you can shorten to just being "*super*" :)

Comment: You need another closing parenthesis to close the opening one after the smiley. (:

Comment: @Neeku: I actually like that the paren is expressing two concepts at once (it's *bisemic* :)

Comment: Haha, nice logic @Dan. Had never thought of it that way. They usually bug me, so I make nested brackets/parentheses! xD

Comment: @Neeku, [How do you end parenthetical statements with emoticons](http://xkcd.com/541/)

Comment: @KyleMit Awesome. I hadn't seen this one. (: One option is using RTL emoticons just like mine. There won't be a mismatch then. xD

Comment: @DanBron I agree, I've always used the bisemic emoticon.

Comment: if parentheses worked that way all of math and programming would collapse.

Comment: (in this self-referential example, is the second smiley in or out of the parenthetical? :) :) now where are we? ;)